# DataTrigger does not work when selecting combobox item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combo box that is to be filled dynamically.

When the user selects an item from the combo box, a label needs to show up.

This works when I use a static combo box, but when the combo box is dynamic it does not. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the `Name` field of the combo box item.

Here is the code :

C#:

```
public ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem> cbItems { get; set; }
public ComboBoxItem SelectedcbItem { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        cbItems = new ObservableCollection<ComboBoxItem>();

        var cbItem = new ComboBoxItem { Content = "<--Select-->"};
        SelectedcbItem = cbItem;
        cbItems.Add(cbItem);

        var cbItem1 = new ComboBoxItem();
        cbItem1.Content = "Option 1";
        cbItem1.Name = "iOne";

        var cbItem2 = new ComboBoxItem();
        cbItem2.Content = "Option 2";
        cbItem2.Name = "iTwo";

        cbItems.Add(cbItem1);
        cbItems.Add(cbItem2);


    }
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Width="130" ItemsSource="{Binding cbItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedcbItem}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>

<Label Content="One is shown" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="6">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=iOne, Path=IsSelected}"    Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"  Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
   </Label>
```

Comment: Do not create UI elements like ComboBoxItem in code behind. Just assign a collection of strings to the ComboBox's ItemsSource and check for that string in the DataTrigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cb"
          ItemsSource="{Binding CbItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCbItem}" .../>

<Label Content="One is shown" ...>
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=SelectedItem}"
                             Value="Option 1">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

with this code behind:

```
public List<string> CbItems { get; }
public string SelectedCbItem { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    cbItems = new List<string> { "Option 1", "Option 2" };
    DataContext = this;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=cb, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="0">
```

---

If you want to make the DataTrigger use a Binding to the source property `SelectedCbItem`, like

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedCbItem}" Value="Option 1">
```

that property must fire a property change notification, e.g. the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: This works. I just realized that this is not a good solution for me. I do now know how many items will be in the combo box, I need to think of something more generic. Thanks.

Comment: Then revert to `ObservableCollection<string>`, and add items as necessary.